# Get rid of *-portlet.xml using annotations. Possible? How?

Tags: spring, configuration, portlet

The documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/portlet.html) says:

> The framework will, on initialization of a DispatcherPortlet, look for
>   a file named [portlet-name]-portlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of
>   your web application and create the beans defined there (overriding
>   the definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global
>   scope).

I do the configuration using annotations if I can, because it feels easier to keep configuration and the actual code in sync. So this [portlet-name]-portlet.xml in my project looks like this (and this file exists maaany time... One for each portlet):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean class="some.path.to.a.Class" />
</beans>
```

That is a lot of XML just for a tiny piece of information: That some.path.to.a.Class should be used to handle requests to [portlet-name]. It would be a lot easier to put a @ForPortlet("[portlet-name]") annotation or something like that on some.path.to.a.Class and forget about this XML file completely. Is anything like that possible? [This bug report](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5700?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3aactivity-stream-issue-tab#issue-tabs) may hint at a "no"/"not yet"?

### SOLUTION

Thanks to the super helpful hints by OlliS (Thanks a lot!) I figured out a way to do it. I dived at the points that OlliS gave me into spring's source and after taking a looooong time to figure out how things work together I wrote the following class:

```
public class MyPortletContext extends
            AbstractRefreshablePortletApplicationContext
    {
        private static final String PORTLET_PACKAGE = "package.where.my.portlets.are.";
        private static final String REMOVE_FROM_NAMESPACE_FOR_PORTLETNAME = "-portlet";

    @Override
    protected void loadBeanDefinitions(DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
            throws BeansException, IOException
    {
        // The following line does the same thing as specifying
        // <context:annotation-config /> in the xml file:
        AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(beanFactory);

        // Figure out the portlet name:
        final String portletName = StringUtils.removeEnd(getNamespace(),
                REMOVE_FROM_NAMESPACE_FOR_PORTLETNAME);
        // Derive the controller from the portlet name:
        final String beanClassName = PORTLET_PACKAGE + portletName;

        // Tell spring about the bean:
        final GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        beanDefinition.setBeanClassName(beanClassName);

        final String beanName = BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.generateBeanName(
                beanDefinition, beanFactory);

        final BeanDefinitionHolder bdHolder = new BeanDefinitionHolder(
                beanDefinition, beanName, new String[] { beanClassName });

        BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.registerBeanDefinition(bdHolder, beanFactory);
    }

}
```

Then I registered this class as contextClass in the portlet.xml file using an init-param, just like OlliS figured in his answer. And that's it. No *-portlet.xml file needed any more. Just a single class configuring all my portlets.

Of course one could still improve this class, making it more flexible, reading the portlet package from somewhere instead of a constant. Maybe an init-param. Or one could scan for annotations, perhaps the mentioned @ForPortlet annotation, which would create the possibility to register more than one bean. But for now I am happy :-).

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using @Configuration annotated classes for configuration? It is a feature in the spring framework as of version 3.0

See the reference documentation here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-java

For example context:component-scan can be enbaled:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ctx.scan("com.acme");
```

Java based configuration can also be combined with XML; mentioned in the documentation.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** 
So you would want to replace the portlet specific context with a java class. I am not sure if the DispatcherPortlet supports java configuration though.
You could try adding something like this which is used in normal webapps:

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>portlet</portlet-name>
    <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
<init-param>
 <!-- Configure DispatcherPortlet to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
       instead of the default XmlPortletApplicationContext ? -->
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>
          org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.acme.web.PortletConfig</param-value>
  </init-param>
<!-- ... -->
</portlet>
```

Some documentation about AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html

From the portlet reference docs:

> ### DispatcherPortlet initialization parameters
>
> ### contextClass
>
> Class that implements WebApplicationContext, which will be used to instantiate the 
>   context used by this portlet. If this parameter isn't specified, the 
>   XmlPortletApplicationContext will be used.

Implementations of WebApplicationContext can be found in the docs:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html

Doesn't seem like there's a portlet specific WebApplicationContext implementation class though, at least I didnt find any. One could always make one :)

Comment: I read through the link you supplied, although it sounds like a good idea, I can just see how it replaces the applicationContext.xml, but not how it can replace the [portlet-name].xml. I completely rewrote my question above to a) include some of my more recent findings and b) to make my question clearer.

Comment: Very helpful hints. I could derive a solution based on your ideas (see my revised question above). Thanks!